Error from order of statements in a while loop
The code snippet in C:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
      int n, sum = 0;
      printf("This program lists terms with each term being sum of previous terms and itself\n");
      printf("Enter integers (0 to terminate): ");

      scanf("%d", &n);
      
      while (n != 0) {
          sum += n;
          scanf("%d", &n);
          printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
      }
}

If I input 1, 2, 3; my expected output is 1, 3 and 6. However 6 is omitted unless I swap the scanf statement with printf statement in the while loop. Why is that?

If you enter 1, 2, 3 then scanf is going to read 3 values and wait for the next one.

You didn't enter the final 0 requested.

If you run your program line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, you should be able to see exactly what is going on, and you should be able to identify in what line your program stops behaving as intended.

You are not going to learn programming by asking a stack overflow question for each code snippet that you are having trouble with. Learn to use a debugger.

Or learn to follow code steps in your head or on paper.

IDK about reopening. Having two statements obviously the wrong way round doesn't make a great archive question. You can see that the code requests two inputs before the first output is made, and if you look carefully at the output, it's not the last 6 that is omitted, but the first 1 is not output until you input the next number.

"unroll" your loop and you will see the problem:
scanf("%d", &n);
// <- 1

sum += n;
scanf("%d", &n);
// <- 2
printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
// -> The sum is: 1

sum += n;
scanf("%d", &n);
// <- 3
printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
// -> The sum is: 3 

// You think you are done here, but you still haven't typed 0 to terminate the program.

sum += n;
scanf("%d", &n);
// <- 0
printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
// -> The sum is: 6

Basically, your print delayed by one number.

The problem with your code is after your entered 3 the program is stuck at the scanf, so it is waiting for the input. To avoid that first print the sum and then read the next input. The number is getting added to the sum but it just not printing to the console.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
      int n, sum = 0;
      printf("This program lists terms with each term being sum of previous terms and itself\n");
      printf("Enter integers (0 to terminate): ");

      scanf("%d", &n);
      
      while (n != 0) {
          sum += n;
          printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
          scanf("%d", &n);
      }
}


OP says this in their question.
